# Как добавить собственный тайл TileProvider на YandexMap?

Tags: android, kotlin, yandex-maps-api

Всем привет. У меня есть класс, который реализует интерфейс `TileProvider`. Я хочу добавить этот тайл на мою карту. В гугл картах это было реализовано вот так:

```
googleMap.addTileOverlay(
                TileOverlayOptions()
                    .tileProvider(provider)
                    .fadeIn(true)
                    .zIndex(index + Z_INDEX_INCREMENT)
            )
```

где provider - собственно, мой класс, реализующий интерфейс. Нашёл для Яндекс карт метод `addLayer()`, который одним из параметров принимает `TileProvider`, однако там помимо этого параметра куча других не нулевых параметров. Скажите пожалуйста, можно ли аналогично гугл картам добавить лишь мой собственный тайл?

Comment: Посмотрите вот этот [пример](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/custom_map)

Comment: @shchedrin но ведь это JS :)

Comment: действительно)
тогда, может [этот пример](https://github.com/yandex/mapkit-android-demo/blob/e4de78b23ba5d4c90dcc45ef5cc35d8329b3debd/src/main/java/com/yandex/mapkitdemo/CustomLayerActivity.java) сможет помочь